# Which species of bird does this feather belong to?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I found a feather at work when cleaning, a pleasant surprise. However, I cannot identify which bird species it belongs it. Between a friend and I, we deduced it to most likely be a falcon feather. However, even with online tools, we are uncertain of which type of falcon it originates from. I am intensely curious. The United States is where I live, in the Midwest.

Here are photos from numerous angles.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Biology Stack Exchange. If you could supply a closer photo of the back edge, thin side (as in your second photo, that'll help with ID and eliminating a couple of suspects.

Comment: @bob1 Added some photos.